# Where the styles are taken from?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a question

I've created new win8 metro app and I don't get from where it is taking styles.
I've change in App.xaml name of styles file. My Style.xaml looks like this

```
<!-- Page layout roots typically use entrance animations and a theme-appropriate background color -->
<Style x:Key="LayoutRootStyle" TargetType="Panel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="ChildrenTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But still I got gold letters, my buttons change white when I'm hover it. Same like with default StandardStyles.xaml

What am I doing wrong ? Or it works just fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style you show would only affect the the panel that uses that style.  If you put a button inside a the panel, the panel's style does not cascade to the button.  The button has its own style, as you correctly deduced from standardstyles.xaml, that controls its appearance.  If you want to change the style of the button, you need to create a new style or update the current style.

Comment: Also - this is different than WPF, where I believe a dependency property like the BackgroundProperty could inherit its value from a visual tree ancestor. In Jupiter it needs to be set explicitly somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you gave your style a key using the **x:Key** attribute. Once a style has a key it will only be applied to controls that implicitly use that named style. If you remove the key, the style should be applied to all controls that match **TargetType** (in this case Panel).